# Ubuntu 18.04 can't detect my laptop's bluetooth

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, settings

I was using Windows 10 until now and at there, a Windows machine could detect my laptop's Bluetooth and I was able to connect to other devices via Bluetooth.
But now in Ubuntu when I go to Setting >> Bluetooth it shows: "No Bluetooth Found" and I am unable to turn on Bluetooth's button.
[Image of what is shown at Setting >> Bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tC95.png)

Could anyone help me?

Edit:
My laptop model is Asus X450CC.

Comment: Laptop model? You have to provide more info, we can't help you otherwise

Comment: My laptop model is Asus X450CC.
Ask me what information I should give to you and I will, I don't know what info I should give. Thanks for your comment. @FliegendeWurst